# De Rham cohomology of the half plane

Tags: differential-geometry, de-rham-cohomology

Maybe this is a basic question, but I am confused. If I consider $M=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2: x_1>0\}$. We have that the De Rham cohomology of M is $H^0(M)=\mathbb{R}$, because M is connected, but what about $H^p(M)$ with $p=1,2$?

Comment: The right half plane is contractible, so it has the cohomology of a point.

Comment: ok, so it is 0.

Comment: That is exactly what it is.